# Take multiple arguments to the thread function c++11

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11

I have an array of threads and in `for` loop I should create a thread to all of them.

The problem is that one of the parameters is `std::move(promise_var)` and another one is structure. When I try to compile it compile gives me an error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘`std::thread::thread(void (&)(Function), Structure [nNumThreads], std::remove_reference<std::promise<const char*>&>::type)`’

So, here is the simplified version of code...

```
func(struct Structure, std::promise<const char *> && v_Promise){
 //doing work
}

main(){
 std::thread a_Threads[5];

 for(int8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   a_Threads[i] = std::threads(func, Structure, std::move(v_promise[i]));
 }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can do what you want but I don't think want to anyways.  In you loop you are moving the same object into each thread.  After the first iteration `v_promise` should no longer be used as its content have been moved into the thread.

Comment: If `func` takes an rvalue reference to an `std::promise`, that means it probably "moves from" `v_promise` and leaves `v_promise` in an unspecified, possibly unusable state. How can every thread use the same object in that case? Either create 5 `v_promise`s, or use an lvalue reference

Comment: Of course, you can use multi-arg threading functions. However, the code has a problem mentioned above, and it is not complete anyways.

Comment: @KABoissonneault I have created. But didn't mentioned it here

Comment: Post a [MCVE].  "this doesn't work" with code that doesn't work because you omitted things is useless.  "this doesn't work" with a pile of unrelated code is useless.  Follow the [MCVE] link and post an actual minimal complete example.

Comment: @KABoissonneault - *How can every thread use the same object in that case*?  A dangling reference is undefined behavior - see "Dangling references" near the bottom of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference  As such, it might "work" - for very liberal definitions of "work".

Answer (score 2):

(Not putting in a comment so that I can append the code properly) I completed the code you submitted so that it compiles and I can confirm that the code below compiles and runs fine with the command `g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

struct Structure{
int el1;
int el2;
};

void func(struct Structure, std::promise<const char *> && v_Promise){
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
    //doing work

}

int main(){
    std::thread a_Threads[5];
    Structure my_struct;
    std::promise<const char*> v_promise;

    for(int8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        a_Threads[i] = std::thread(func, my_struct, std::move(v_promise));

    }
}
```

Please cross-reference this against any typos or information that you might have omitted.

Comment: Yep, using both clang++ (3.8) and g++ (4.9), it prints hello a few times.

Comment: Are you sure func is declared as void?

Comment: Can you run the code I posted? If not, there might be a problem with your libraries.

Comment: Do you really need to compile with `-pthread` to use `<thread>`?

Comment: On my setup, yeah, tried it without and wouldn't compile

Comment: Yeah, cool! It worked. My problem was that I forgot that made an array of structures, thats why compile showed me an error! But thanks anyway

Comment: Glad you sorted it out! Good luck :)